# Flutter- How NOT to call the same Service over and over?

Tags: flutter, async-await, flutter-web

Suppose that my goal is to display an "endless" list of recommended items to the user.

To do so, I've implemented some async method getItemsFromServer(...) which is very expensive (in terms of server usage,time,battery etc) and gets 100 new items (and their images) from the server, and updates the state of the recommended items screen by adding the items which were fetched from the server.

My goal is to call this function only when the user has less than ,say, 20 items that he didn't view yet.
The problem is that if I'll program it naively,for example

```
if(itemsNotViewed<20){
getItemsFromServer(...)
}
```

after the user has clicked or viewed some new item, this async method will be called around 20 times...
What's the most principled way to call the method only once and wait for it to complete,while not interfering with the user's experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The future object itself is pretty useful to remember whether something is going on. Something like this should work. Ideally you would put it into a function that you call from multiple places.

```
class MyState ... {

  Future itemsBeingGotten;


  build() {
    ...
      onPress: () async {
        if (itemsBeingGotten == null && itemsNotViewed < 20) {
          try {
            itemsBeingGotten = getItemsFromServer()
            await itemsBeingGotten; 
          } finally {
            itemsBeingGotten = null;
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: I thought about something like that,and my issue was -this means that I should use some lock() mechanism, since different threads access/use the same resource (itemsBeingGotten) at the same time. Do you think it's a concern? Why?

Comment: Good news: it's not a concern! There is only one thread. Dart is single threaded. Async simulates multiple tasks in one event loop. No other code gets in between until you say `await`. I try to explain it in much detail in this talk of mine: https://youtu.be/vPHxckiSmKY?t=2348